# How to set up isc-dhcp-server to set all router NICs to the same ip and give out static and dynamic ips based on the interface?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, ip, dhcp

I am assembling a set of server/router devices to be used as a provider of some offline services for the local network.I don't need WAN, each server is isolated and for each server I have a set of ethernet NICs and 2 WNICs. I will be running hostapd to create 2.4 and 5Ghz wireless APs.

Each client should find router/server at the same IP (192.168.0.1) and
I want to dynamically assign ip addresses to the wireless clients, but eth0 and eth1 clients must always get the same static ips.

So far all tutorials for routers split each nic into its own subnet, this would solve how ip addresses are assigned on different interfaces, but then the server ip is different for clients on different interfaces. The second way is to create a bridge, but how would I give out constant static IPs to the ethX devices? is there a way to determine when the clients connect?

Comment: What kind of router are you using? It has to support port based address allocation. This would be easier on a switch where you could assign each a port a different VLAN and then limit the VLAN to one addressable value. You can then make rules for all the VLANS to be able to talk to your servers that are on a different subnet.

Comment: It is a board with Cortex A53 running Linux 4.14 with onboard and usb/pcie nics

Comment: Check this link, I think what you want is option 82 for dhcp: http://www.miquels.cistron.nl/isc-dhcpd/  Basically makes it so if you plug anything into X port it gives a specific address.